# Prove the equality of two definite integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to prove this equality? What is the general approach in proving such equalities?
$$\int_{0}^{1} x^{1000} (1 - x)^{200} \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} x^{200} (1 - x)^{1000} \, dx$$

Comment: Try to make the following substitution: $x\mapsto 1-x$

Comment: Hmm – if only we could replace $x$ by $1-x$ and vice versa in an integral ....

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:
$$ L = \int_{0}^{1} x^{1000} (1 - x)^{200} \, dx = - \int_{u(0)}^{u(1)} (1-u)^{1000} u^{200} \, du = - \int_{1}^{0} (1-u)^{1000} u^{200} \, du
$$
Then:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} (1-u)^{1000} u^{200} \, du \equiv
\int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^{1000} x^{200} \, dx 
$$ and done.

Comment: A remark for you - this is the Beta function and it has relationships to the Gamma function.

Comment: Please, do not answer very low-quality questions anymore.